# Magento v2 Template file not called from layout file

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to **add one static block section in the product pages** from **custom module** but cannot find it working. **product.phtml** template file call is not working from the layout xml file **catalog_product_view.xml**. Below are my code and filenames. I can see `style.css` and `script.js` working which is included in layout xml file head tag from which I can say the module is working fine but the template is not called.

Any insights could be very helpful.

### catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link src="GBD_GAEcommerce::script.js"/>     <!-- this is working -->
    <css src="GBD_GAEcommerce::style.css"/>      <!-- this is working -->
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <block class="GBD\GAEcommerce\Block\ProductInfo" template="GBD_GAEcommerce::product.phtml" name="product.gainfo" after="-"/>
    </referenceBlock>                            <!-- this is not working -->
</body>
</page>
```

### Block/ProductInfo.php

```
<?php
namespace GBD\GAEcommerce\Block;
class ProductInfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
)
{        
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getCurrentCategory()
{        
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}

public function getCurrentProduct()
{        
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
}    

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try using your code It's working Please check template path.

For plugin path.
GBD/GAEcommerce/view/frontend/templates/product.phtml

For design folder path
 GBD_GAEcommerce/templates/product.phtml

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your answer.